# Linux shell script for files older than certain amount of time

Tags: shell

I have a backup of MySQL databases and the backup file have time and date in their names, like this:

```
daily_amavisd_2016-10-01_05h28m_Saturday.sql.gz 
daily_amavisd_2016-10-02_05h28m_Sunday.sql.gz 
daily_amavisd_2016-10-03_05h28m_Monday.sql.gz
```

I need a script to check if the oldest file in the folder `/backup/amavisd/daily` is not older than one week. If it is older than one week, it should give me the status `"backup failed"`, if it is not older than one week, it should give me the status `"backup OK"`.

Can someone help me with shell script for that?

Answer (score 0):

this could help you, if you want to prints file name and status;

```
#!/bin/bash

find /backup/amavisd/daily/ -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c '
file_date=$(echo $1|cut -f 3 -d '_');
start_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "-7 days");
    if [[ "$file_date" > "$start_date" ]]; then
        echo "$1: backup OK"
    else
        echo "$1: backup failed"
    fi' -- {} \;
```

Eg;

```
user@host:/tmp/test$ ./test.sh
backup/amavisd/daily/daily_amavisd_2016-10-01_05h28m_Saturday.sql.gz: backup OK
backup/amavisd/daily/daily_amavisd_2016-10-03_05h28m_Monday.sql.gz: backup OK
backup/amavisd/daily/daily_amavisd_2016-10-02_05h28m_Sunday.sql.gz: backup OK
backup/amavisd/daily/daily_amavisd_2016-10-07_05h28m_Monday.sql.gz: backup OK
backup/amavisd/daily/daily_amavisd_2016-09-07_05h28m_Monday.sql.gz: backup failed
```

Comment: Thank you. But I just need 1 status at the end OK or NOT OK, because I will use that script with some other software. If one file is older than 1 week than status is NOT OK.